# Can I change the width and height of a div using javascript scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

My div covers the whole screen i.e., the div width and height is 100%. And i want a scroll event to decrease the width and height of that div on scroll up and increase the width and height of the div on scroll down. Is it possible? Please help me out here.If i add scroll event here it doesn't work maybe because the scroll doesn't happen as the div fits the whole screen.

here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myfunc()">
        <div class="firstdiv">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
function myfunc(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("firstdiv");
    console.dir(x);
    x[0].style.width = "100%";
    x[0].style.height = "100%";
    x[0].style.background = "red";
    x[0].style.position = "relative";
    x[0].style.top = "0";
    x[0].style.left = "0";
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] - Provide a [mcve].

Comment: okay sure, i will edit the question with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this can help you

```
<body style="overflow: scroll; height: 1000px;" onload="scrollDetect()">
    <div class="firstdiv" style="border:1px solid black; margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;height: 200px;">
    </div>

    <script>
        function scrollDetect() {
            let div = document.querySelector('.firstdiv')
            var lastScroll = 0;
            window.onscroll = function () {
                let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Get Current Scroll Value
                if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
                    lastScroll = currentScroll;
                    div.style.width = '50%'
                    div.style.height = "50%";
                    div.style.background = "red";
                    div.style.position = "relative";
                    div.style.top = "0";
                    div.style.left = "0";
                } else {
                    lastScroll = currentScroll;
                    div.style.width = '200px'
                    div.style.height = '200px'
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll

You can set the `.onscroll` event on the area you want to change the size of, or perhaps on the entire body if you want the user to be able to scroll past the element you're resizing.